# converting negative integer into HEX in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

How to convert negative number into hexa decimal in flex ?

For eg : -73715 ...the hex value for this number is FFFEE00D

how can i get this in flex ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uint(yourInt).toString(16)`

Should do.